# Visual Basic: How to replace selected NumericUpDowns with ComboBoxes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, replace

Is it possible to replace the selected `NumericUpDown` controls with `ComboBoxes`?

I understand that not all properties can be conserved but the only properties I need are the location and the size.
The workflow I have in mind is as follows:

1. Select certain `NumericUpDowns`
2. Click replace with... and then select `ComboBoxes` (or any other approach)
3. Where the `NumericUpDowns` were, there are now `ComboBoxes` of the same size

The reason I want to do this is that I have to put together a GUI with multiple tabs. Each tab page has a list of `Labels` with either `NumericUpDowns` or `ControlBoxes` next to it. The order of the controls changes per tab. I just want to copy the items on the first tab and paste them on the other tabs. Then per tab I only have to change certain `NumericUpDowns` into `ComboBoxes`.

I started with VB yesterday so I might be overlooking something.

Comment: There's no refactoring support for what you want to do built into VS, I'm afraid. You can possibly do it with Developer Express's [CodeRush](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/), but not in the standard VS2008 or 2010.

Comment: Is this to happen at Run-Time or as Ken understood is it at design-time?

Comment: ok, then you'll have to actually do a Find on NumericUpDowns and Replace with comboboxes. This is a coding exercise and VS is the editor - unless you made something like a Visual Studio plugin as Ken said this isn't available.

Comment: As I generated these controls visually from the toolbox and not with code I can not do a find and replace. Too bad this is not possible with Visual Studio. Thank you all for the effort though.

Comment: yes you can - say its WinForms you just open a Form.vb then put the mouse cursor over the InitializeComponent and press goto definition - thats where all the form designer code is. Backup before you edit these files. If its web then its your ASPX page, if its WPF its your XAML

Comment: Sorry, I have looked through all the menus and the help file, but I did not encounter InitializeComponent and go to definition. I'm using VS2008 Professional Edition. When I  opne Form.vb I see the GUI window. Where do I click on the InitializeComponent? Sorry for this basic questions, but this is my second day using VS so please bear with me.

Comment: double click the Form.vb, you'll see the code and in the Form_Load event you'll see the call to InitialiseComponent. Right click on the word and select Goto Definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The quickest is doing it manually, we cant change your GUI remotely - since you are at an entry level with a language you do not know well, RAD is the best recommendation - this way you can study what it does - just like learning HTML with DreamWeaver's RAD tools.**

Since your interested, *(I know your new to VB so I'dd make it heaps clear)* you do these steps:

a) Open Winforms VS 2008 solution
b) Click the File > Create New Project > WinForms
c) Double click the form and it will show you the forms code
d) Then in the constructor method you will see the line `InitializeComponent`
e) Right Click on this method call and chose `Goto Definition`
f) This will show you the code that populates the form with controls
g) Then for each form I'm suggestion you replace all the NumericUpDown's with ComboBoxes  in the xyz.Designer.vb file

However I'd really recommend doing it with Visual Studio IDE. Don't be frightened.

Comment: We must be using different programs. I click File -> New. I click on the "Windows Forms Application" template from the Visual Basic - Windows project type. I double click on Form1.db. The designer opens. I right click on Form.db and click "View code" and I see: `Public Class Form1

End Class`  Nothing else. I think it is clear that what I want can not be done and therefore I give up this question. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: OK no problems, but for the record double clicking the form takes you to code view and from memory it does make a Form_Load event. Alternatively when viewing the Form Design, press F4 to see the Form properties - click the Lighting Bolt button to see the Form Events and double click the Form_Load event

Answer (score 1):

```
Private sub Replace_By_ComboBox(ByVal nud As NumericUpDowns)

    'Create new combo box        
    Dim cbx As New ComboBox
    cbx.Left = nud.Left
    cbx.To = nud.Top
    cbx.Width = nud.Width
    cbx.Height = nud.Height
    cbx.Visible = True
    cbx.Enabled = True

    'Add the combo box 
    nud.Parent.Controls.Add(cbx)

    'Remove the NumericUpDowns
    nud.Parent.Controls.Remove(nud)

End Sub
```

Comment: Does work in run-time indeed (after correcting small typo's), but that was not what I needed. I should've been more clear in the question, sorry